# SQL database/column name convention + language code

Tags: database, naming-conventions

Usually in master tables we have a `name` column and it is usually in English.
But what is the best column naming convention if we have it in different languages. Is `en_name` better than `name_en`?
( keep in mind, i will use JPA and entities). For now, I will need the following columns:

- `en_name` for English.
- `ar_name` for Arabic.
- `fr_name` for French.
- `de_name` for German.

  Also, which is better to use the two letters ISO 639-1 codes or three letters ISO 639-2 Code?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need. If you need just a separate columns to store in DB name translations, I'll recommend to use `name_de`, `name_en` ..., but it's just my preference, it's easy to read and understand purpose of column.

But think about filtering (searching). If you prefere this aprouch with additional columns in the same table, you will need to add some kind of switch in query (stored procedure) to search name for specific language - for English you need to search in `name_en`, German - `name_de`. So I could recommend solution with separate table for localization with columns `id`, `[master_table]_id`, `language_code` and `text` (or name).

For example, there is a table `item` with columns `id`and `name`.
I would create table `item_localization` with columns `id`, `item_id`, `language_code` and `text`.
So for row (1, "name") in table `item` in `item_localization` will be (1, 1, "en", "name-en"), (1, 2, "de", "name-de").

I prefere to store in master table English name and also duplicate it in localization table. In this case it's easy to filter by localized name, something like

```
select item.*
from item
join item_localization on item_localization.item_id = item.id
where item_localization.language_code = "de" and item_localization.text like "%some_text%"
```

But it's just my experience and thoughts.